# How can I properly read in this text data to a list?

Tags: python

I have some data in a `.txt` file structured as follows:

```
Soup    Tomato
Beans    Kidney
.
.
.
```

I read in the data with

```
combo=open("combo.txt","r") 
lines=combo.readlines()
```

However, the data is then appears as

```
lines=['Soup\tTomato\r\n','Beans\tKidney\r\n',...]
```

I would like each entry to be its own element in the list, like

```
lines=['Soup','Tomato',...]
```

And even better would be to have two lists, one for each column.

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this or fix my problem?

Comment: You want `strip.()` and `.split()`.

Comment: Are you sure about that result for `lines`?  `'Beans\nKidney\r\n'` looks suspicious -- the example makes it seem more like there would be a `\t` between `Beans` and `Kidney`, not `\n`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  My mistake, there is a `\t` between `Beans` and `Kidney`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split the lines:

```
lines = [a_line.strip().split() for a_line in combo.readlines()]
```

Or without using readlines:

```
lines = [a_line.strip().split() for a_line in combo]
```

Comment: Very nice solution... however it doesn't do what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You look like your opening a csv tab delimeted file.

use the python csv class.

```
lines = []
with open('combo.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:        
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        lines += row
print(lines)
```

now as a list.

or with a list of lists you can invert it ...

```
lines = []
with open('combo.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:        
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        line.append(rows) # gives you a list of lists. 

columns = map(list, zip(*lines))
columns[0] = ['Soup','Beans',...];
```

Comment: @AdamSmith not in my python ?

Comment: Oops you're right -- I thought you did `lines.append(row)`

Comment: I still think a list of lists is a better representation of the data, than a single list. how would you know whats on each line and what line it is on ?

Comment: I agree, but it's not what OP wants for some strange reason :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the items in a single list:

```
>>> with open('combo.txt','r') as f:
...    all_soup = f.read().split()
...
>>> all_soup
['Soup', 'Tomato', 'Beans', 'Kidney']
```

If you want to get each column, then do this:

```
>>> with open('combo.txt','r') as f:
...    all_cols = zip(*(line.strip().split() for line in f))
...
>>> all_cols
[('Soup', 'Beans'), ('Tomato', 'Kidney')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module to handle csv-like files (in this case, tab-separated values, not comma-separated values).

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('path/to/file.tsv') as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(reader))
```

`csv.reader` turns your file into a list of lists, essentially:

```
def reader(file, delimiter=",")
    with open('path/to/file.tst') as tsvfile:
        result = []
        for line in tsvfile:
            sublst = line.strip().split(delimiter)
            result += sublst
    return result
```